# Touchend event not working correctly with touches array

Tags: javascript

Lately I've started playing with touch events in javascript and I encountered a strange problem with touchend event (propably something obvious and I'm just too dumb to understand it). So basically, here is my code:

```
function send(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.body.innerHTML = e.type + "<br>" + e.targetTouches[0].pageY;
}

['touchstart', 'touchmove', 'touchend'].forEach(function(e) {
    window.addEventListener(e, send, false);
});
```

And now the *e.targetTouches[0].pageY* works fine, but the *e.type* will only assume touchstart or touchmove value, not the touchend for some reason. I noticed that it only happens when I try to call the *e.type* property in the same line or after reading any property from the event.targetTouches (or event.touches) array. Aren't those properties read-only? Why does it brake my code?

Oh, and after few hours of playing with it I noticed that the event.type will assume the touchend value only when holding one finger on the screen and then tapping it with another, still that doesn't solve my problem,.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because touchend event is fired when touch point is removed.

No touch point, no targetTouches.

MDN [TouchEvent.targetTouches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/targetTouches)

A TouchList listing all the Touch objects for **touch points** that are **still in contact with the touch surface**

MDN [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/Events/touchend)

The **touchend** event is fired when a **touch point is removed from the touch surface**

To solve your problem, recording the targetTouches when touchstart and touchmove, and use it when touch point is removed:

```
var TargetTouches;

function send(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var type = e.type;
    var pageY;

    if (type !== 'touchend') {
      pageY = e.targetTouches[0].pageY;
      TargetTouches = e.targetTouches[0];
    } else {
      pageY = TargetTouches.pageY;
    }

    document.body.innerHTML = type + "<br>" + pageY;
}

['touchstart', 'touchmove', 'touchend'].forEach(function(e) {
    window.addEventListener(e, send, false);
});
```

Comment: How does that solve my problem? Touchend event works fine, let's say the first line in send function is something like "alert(e.type);" then when I tap the screen it will alert both "touchstart" and "touchend" but when I try to alert it after event.targetTouches[0].someProperty (or event.touches[0].someProperty) the touchend event magically disappears like it never fired, touchstart and touchmove works fine though...

Comment: remove the code 'e.targetTouches[0].pageY', then you can see the touchend event is fired, not disapeared

Comment: As I stated in my question I already know that "e.targetTouches[0].pageY" is causing problems with touchend, but rather then avoiding the problem I want to either fix it or understand why it won't work and find some alternative way to do this. Removing this gives me nothing.

Comment: Thanks! Now with an example it makes perfect sense to me, my fault for comparing the touch events to mouse events where mouseup still records the coordinates.